# Asking a new questions opens and old question

Tags: support, asking-questions, draft

I press on the Ask Question button. One of my old questions is exhibited. 
Must I assume therefore, that if I edit the old question and press the Submit button, my old question will be substituted by my new question?

This would be a completely avoidable result.

If not, the user should be informed that the old question is exhibited only for templating or for other reasons.

Comment: there is a discard button somewhere next to the submit button i think. it saves it like gmail as a draft

Answer (score 6):

All posts are [saved before posting as a draft](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/168244) once every 45 seconds. You'll notice a `draft saved` below the post:

[image]

Only once the draft is saved, the [`discard` draft option will be made available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207723/168244).

Discard any drafts - you're allowed one per question and answer - to avoid seeing it again when posting.

Reference: [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/168244)